# Manga with a repeated isekai and a white chamber where he can buy skills and equipment

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I’m searching for the name of a webtoon/manga where the main character has an isekai every week (I think) with a mission. And if he completes the mission he can return to his original world at 17:00 (I think). The webtoon/manga has a white chamber where he can buy skills, equipment... and he decides to be a healer/dps. He has the blessing of a goddess.

He's also with a rich girl who buys the skills to be a fire mage and in the real world he became his bodyguard to be prepared when they are transported. Everything he has on him is also transported to the world.

And before entering in this world he has to do tests in a dungeon.

I remember a mission when they need to defeat a chief orc and his legion. After the orc was defeated, they sell his weapon to the chief of the adventurers guild. After they leave the room, the chief calls someone and says "tell ? (I don't remember) that two people from the white room appeared".

I don't remember exactly when I read this manga, but I'm sure it was before 2018.

Comment: Gokufuri Kyohi Shite Tesaguri Sutato!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/5jveib/need_help_finding_a_manga_i_read_a_while_ago/) says it might be [Life Howling](https://mangakakalot.com/read-pb6au158504871950).

> Jung Yoon-hwan may be an orphan but he was a college student who was focusing hard on his studies, one day he is brought to a mysterious "White room" to fight even when he does not want to. Every time he defeats these monsters he gains psychic power, magic, and items beyond his imaginations....

Comment: Please don’t rollback an edit so this is pretty much a link only answer. This should have some content to it either about the manga in general or how it matches the description.

Comment: it’s perfectly fine to quote material written by others, you may want to check out the [help page on referencing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). In fact it is actually heavily encouraged if you cannot do so in your own words. That means that in this case as it originally stood had one of the links gone down they would have been useless and it would leave users having to research it themselves which is something we don’t really want. An answer should stand up on its own and in this case that means having something about the manga in question in the answer.

Comment: Dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275696/a-man-is-summoned-to-a-white-room-where-he-defeats-a-monster-to-gain-points-he-u, where the answer was edited into the question by the querent. Not certain which way the dupe out to go...