# A man is summoned to a white room where he defeats a monster to gain points he uses the points to get a healing skill

Tags: story-identification, manga

In the first few chapters time stops at a certain time at night then people get transported to a white room. Their first challenge is to defeat a monster. The second challenge they get transported to a forest but this time there are two people, one is a girl with orange hair with fire powers and the other is a guy with red hair and has healing powers.

The girl uses her fire powers to start a forest-fire (ending the challenge) and gains points for killing the zombies/skeletons.

It is not a manga it’s a manhua and I don't think it's being updated because I have not seen it on any recently updated or it’s finished because last time I read it was 3 years ago and the first time I read it was probably 2018 or 17ish.

I found it it’s called life howling if you see this you should check it out it is pretty good for when it was released and even write now when manhua, manhwa type books are popular.

Comment: If it's not a manga then what is it? A light novel, presumably

Comment: Could you [edit] to add clarification.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SF&F!  Not being updated?  Is this something you saw on the web?  When did you read it?  Was it new or old then?  Please give us a bit more to go on.  The more details you include, the more likely it is that we can help you.

Comment: @Davonte - Rather than editing the answer into the question, why not post the answer as an actual answer (using the 'Your Answer' field below)? You'll likely earn some upvotes for the effort, and if you don't post an answer here, someone else likely will sooner or later (and they'll get the upvotes instead of you). If you do post an actual answer to this question, please also remember to mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case Davonte does not return, they edited the answer into their question, *[Life Howling](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/life-howling)*, based off of [a webnovel by the same name](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/life-howling/).

[image: Front cover of Life Howling]

> Jung Yoon-hwan may be an orphan but he was a college student who was focusing hard on his studies. One day he is brought to a mysterious "White room" to fight even when he does not want to. Every time he defeats these monsters he gains psychic power, magic, and items beyond his imaginations...

[This review](https://www.novelupdates.com/fdrev/?comid=19276&sid=7654) mentions the white room:

> It follows the main character who is one day transported to a white room and is instantly thrown into a tutorial fight (he takes on basically a paladin class). Later on he meets potential allies with their own quirks and special abilities (the main heroine is a bit dull in the manwha imo but maybe it will be different in the novel).
>
> Everytime he finishes the time period inside the world he will get points which can be spent on equipment, skills, which can also be upgraded and then gets booted out. Everything stays with him though in the real world, however in the start they only spend 1 day in the real world before getting transported back in.

And indeed, the comic has been on "indefinite hiatus" [for at least 7 years](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/5bz2fe/life_howling_dropped_by_the_author/) while the author focuses on their other properties, such as *Wizardly Tower* and *The Gamer*.